# Why does Magento 2 use <span> in buttons

Tags: magento2, cart, luma-theme, ui

This is probably something I should know, so excuse the question, but why does Magento use  inside buttons, and especially inside the checkout it binds the data (which I understand why but not why it is better - it is not like this could ever handle translations, the raw text is still in there).

For example, as is:

```
<button data-role="review-save" type="submit"
        data-bind="click: placeOrder($parents[1]), attr: {title: $t('Place Order')}"
        class="button action primary checkout"><span data-bind="i18n: 'Place Order'"></span></button>
```

Can I change it to:

```
<button data-role="review-save" type="submit"
        data-bind="click: placeOrder($parents[1])"
        class="button action primary checkout">Place Order</button>
```

When I am working through customising the cart to suit us, is there a legitimate reason to avoid?

Now time to tell me why I am so wrong with this simplified version :)